# Flip between Dynamic Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have A listview showing list of available users.. and on clicking I show A chat Screen passing Intent As in below snippet
Now I want to save the Instance of this activity(chat screen) and when I get back to any screen I want to fling through all open chat screens....
But the problem is that since chat screen is only single activity it's getting destroyed on Back button .. How Do i achieve What I am trying to do.

I have gone through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)
But not getting the way out..

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {

             Intent i = new Intent();
             i.setClass(DisplayUser.this, MessageActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position + 1));
             i.putExtra("icon", userlist.get(position).getIcon());
             i.putExtra("name", userlist.get(position).getName());
             startActivity(i);
             recent_id.add(userlist.get(position).getId());
        }
```

Comment: [You should learn about Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) and [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: but can't I do it by this method?
As fragments are only available from api 11 i suppose

Answer (score 0):

May be these two things can help you: [alwaysRetainTaskState](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always) and [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode)